# Configure JSDoc annotation behaviour in VSCode - similar to the @deprecated annotation

Tags: visual-studio-code

Out of the box VSCode supports JSDoc quite well.

For example, if we use the `@deprecated` annotation, then references of that symbol will be shown with strikethrough.

[image]

I have a situation where I want to mark some functions private or protected (note, I'm not talking in a sense of object oriented encapsulation, I'm not doing OO). That is, they're not necessarily deprecated - I just want to restrict where the functions are intended to be called - and give a visual warning as such.

I think the `@access private` or `@private` annotation seems appropriate for this.

For example some code might look like:

```javascript
/**
 * @access private
 */
export function oldFunction() {

} 


/**
 * Developers should call this function, instead of calling oldFunction directly. 
 */
export function newFunction() {

    oldFunction(); 
}
```

The answer isn't to do something like restrict the export of `oldFunction` - as there will be existing code calling oldFunction directly, which I want to progressively tidy up.

So the question is - I'd quite like VSCode to style the reference to `oldFunction` in strikethrough, or something similar. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: I still think what you want fits the definition of _deprecated_ precisely, from the perspective of a (potential) caller.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of answers to this question may be found in the post
[Is it possible to toggle text to strikethrough text in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899780/is-it-possible-to-toggle-text-to-strikethrough-text-in-visual-studio-code)

Here is the accepted
[answer by Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49907153/165358) :

> You can make <strike>strikethrough</strike> in vscode with the help of
> [TODO
> Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight)
> extension:
>
> ```json
> "todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "(~~.+?~~)|(✔.+?\n)|(\\[x\\].+\n)",
> "todohighlight.defaultStyle": {
>     "color": "none",
>     "backgroundColor": "none",
>     "textDecoration": "line-through"
> },
> ```
>
> Use patterns that you usually use for **done** todos. The above works
> for such:
>
> ```
> [x] done
> ✔ done
> ~~done~~
> ```
>
> After that you can either use plain typing or find some toggling
> extension or write one yourself.

Another
[answer by humility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416227/165358)
recommends using
[Strike for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=artdiniz.strike-vscode).
It is remarked that enabling "strike.whitespace" in *Settings>Extensions>Strike* will avoid `-` characters inserted between
white-space.